# Perl - How to split input into an array?

Tags: linux, perl

I have a small Perl script that is used to take user command line input, and then splitting the input into an array where each **service** should be its own element.

My goal is to enable single arguments, as well as several arguments using a split character where every argument is separated by a comma sign. Examples of these would be:

- ssh
- ssh,named,cups

My code looks as follows, it does compile without errors but the output is not the intended.

```
    print "Please provide the service name that you wish to analyze (Named service):\n";
    print "Several services may be provided, using a comma sign as a separator.\n";

    my $service_name_input = <>;
    chomp($service_name_input);
    my @service_list = split(/,/, $service_name_input);

    foreach my $line (@service_list)
    {
        open(my $service_input, "service @service_list status|");
    }

    foreach my $line (@service_list)
    {
        #Matches for "running".
        if ($line =~ m/(\(running\))/)
        {
            print "The service @service_list is running\n";
        }
        #Matches for "dead".
        elsif ($line =~ m/(dead)/)
        {
            print "The service @service_list is dead\n";
        }
    }
```

The program should output if the **service** is running or dead, but I only get the following error code. When manually issuing the **service** command, it works just fine though.

> The service command supports only basic LSB actions (start, stop,
>   restart, try-restart, reload, force-reload, status). For other
>   actions, please try to use systemctl.

Any help regarding the steps I should take in order to achieve a working program will be much appreciated. Thank you for reading.

Comment: `open(my $service_input, "service @service_list status|");` -> `open(my $service_input, "service $line status|");`

Comment: It doesn't result in any errors, but I do not get any output either. I think it might have something to do with the print statement then.

Comment: You don't actually use `$service_input` aside from opening it. You might want to capture the output somehow.

Comment: You are correct. I will take a look at that.

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach my $line (@service_list)
{
    open(my $service_input, "service @service_list status|");
}
```

This loop doesn't use `$line`. You're passing the whole array `@service_list` to the service command, i.e. you're running `service ssh named cups status`. This causes an error because `service` thinks you want to execute the `named` action on the `ssh` service. To fix that, write `"service $line status |"`.

But there's another issue: You never do anything with `$service_input` either. If you want to loop over each line of each service command output, you need something more like:

```
foreach my $service (@service_list)
{
    open(my $service_input, '-|', 'service', $service, 'status')
        or die "$0: can't run 'service': $!\n";

    while (my $line = readline $service_input)
    {
        #Matches for "running".
        if ($line =~ m/(\(running\))/)
        {
            print "The service $service is running\n";
        }
        #Matches for "dead".
        elsif ($line =~ m/(dead)/)
        {
            print "The service $service is dead\n";
        }
    }
}
```

I've changed your `open` line to use a separate mode argument `-|` (which is good style in general) and the list form of process open, which avoids the shell, which is also good in general (no issues with "special characters" in `$service`, for example).

Comment: With pipe `open`s, don't forget to check the return value of `close` to see if the command actually succeeded (`open` only returns the pid of the child, so you're really checking the success of `fork`).

Comment: I understand all of your changes but `readline`. I'm not sure what this is supposed to do.

Comment: @MajesticPixel It does just what it sounds like: reads...wait for it...lines. :) That bit of code is reading the output of your command line-by-line and storing the result in the scalar `$line`. See [`perldoc -f readline`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/readline.html) (linked for your convenience)

Comment: I tried this but somehow the variables `$service_input` and `$service` require explicit package name even though they have that.